# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Im trying to make a shrinking header, I almost have it working however i keep getting the above error for this section of the js files

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

var docElem = document.documentElement,
    header = document.querySelector( '.cbp-af-header' ),
    didScroll = false,
    changeHeaderOn = 300;

function init() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}

function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            var windowtab = $(window).width();
            if (windowtab >= 1021)
            {
            classie.add( header, 'cbp-af-header-shrink' );
            }
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'cbp-af-header-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
}

function scrollY() {
    return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
}

init();
})();
```

and

```
var classie = {
// full names
 hasClass: hasClass,
addClass: addClass,
removeClass: removeClass,
toggleClass: toggleClass,
 // short names
has: hasClass,
 add: addClass,
remove: removeClass,
toggle: toggleClass
};
```

I had it working in DNN when I add a module for the jQuery however when I had it to the skin, I end up with the above console error

Comment: If you're including jQuery, why not use jQuery everywhere else? Where does this error come from? (it's not directly from any of the code you posted). Is it from jQuery?

Comment: There's no 'classList' anywhere in the above code... where is it throwing?

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: We can't help if you don't show the code where the error occurs, but at a guess, looking at what you *did* provide, `header` is `null` because as of when you do the `header = document.querySelector( '.cbp-af-header' )` line, there is no matching element in the document. (Perhaps you need to move the script to the end of the page.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your comment. Moving all JS script to the end of the page; is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This line in the script:

```
header = document.querySelector('.cbp-af-header')
```

#### [@ MDN for document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

it says that, *the first element in the document with the class is returned*.

---

So may be you are looking for `.querySelectorAll("selector/s")`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".cbp-af-header");
```

#### [@ MDN for document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)

**returns a list** of all elements *(div in case)* supplied within the document.

Comment: elem.classList.remove( c ); got an error remove is undefined

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. I realized that IIFE was executed before the DOM was completely loaded. If you are use jQuery, try wrapping it in $(document).ready()